# jQuery Toggle different result in IE11

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, toggle, internet-explorer-11

I am using the following code to toggle a dropdown menu.
This jQuery works fine in all browsers except IE11. Any idea why?

Using latest jQuery version.

```
$j('#clicker').click(function() {
    $j('#clicker').not(this).siblings('ul').slideUp("slow");

    $j(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle("slow");
});


$j('#clicker').blur(function() {
    $j('#dropdown-inside').hide('slow', function() {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your jquery to 1.11 and assuming your div id is dropdown-inside add a style with a height in pixels like:

```
<div id="dropdown-inside" style="height:100px">
```